# I am getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError from String manipulation

Tags: java

Trying to remove all characters between `"<>"` characters, works fine for up to `500` character strings, after that, I get the following error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

The String I need to do this to has `21,000+` characters. Struggling to see why what is reducing the size of the String would make it crash.

```
private static String removeGarbage(String resultString) throws IOException {               
    int lineLen = resultString.length();

    while (resultString.indexOf("<")>=0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lineLen; i++) {
            if (resultString.indexOf("<")<=0)
                break;
            resultString = resultString.substring(0,resultString.indexOf("<")) + resultString.substring(resultString.indexOf(">")+1, resultString.length());
        }
    }

    return resultString;
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop makes no sense to me ... why do you iterate through every char and create substrings?

Comment: why are you doing a `for` cycle inside a `while`? Can you just use one of them?

Comment: "<a>b<c>".replaceAll("[<>]", "")

Comment: Unfortunately "<a>b<c>".replaceAll("[<>]", "") doesn't work as I need to replace all the characters between "<" and ">". So the string "{{<"}<>}{<o}<ui'<>}}" would become "{{}{}}" for example.

Comment: Also the for loop wasn't necessary, I have removed it now thanks, still having the same issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly simple regular expression should do it:

```
String input = "{{<\"}<>}{<o}<ui'<>}}";
String output = input.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");

System.out.println(output); // {{}{}}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, works perfectly! But how does it work?

Comment: Read up on regular expression syntax. The expression above basically selects all sequences of `<`, followed by zero or more characters that are not `>`, followed by `>`, and replaces them with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid creating many large `String` values by using regular expression replacement:

```
private static String removeGarbage(String resultString) {
    return resultString.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "");
}
```

- `\\<` matches the opening bracket
- `.*?` matches anything in between
- `\\>` matches the closing bracket

Answer (score -2):

Just use a `substring` call with two `indexOf` calls.
An extended example here:

```
Integer begin = resultString.indexOf("<");
Integer end = resultString.indexOf(">", begin);
return resultString.substring(begin, end);
```

Comment: Thanks but this is what I am already doing, as I said though, when passing larger strings though this it crashes.

Comment: Sry. I expected that your code crashes cause the for-loop inside the while-loop.